# Spark Scala, grabbing the max value of 1 column, but keep all columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with 3 columns (customer, associations, timestamp).

I want to grab the latest `customer` by looking at timestamps.

#### Attempt

```
val rdd = readRdd.select(col("value"))
val val_columns = Seq("value.timestamp").map(x => last(col(x)).alias(x))
rdd.orderBy("value.timestamp")
   .groupBy("value.customer")
   .agg(val_columns.head, val_columns.tail: _*)
   .show()
```

I believe the above code is working, but trying to figure out how to include all columns (ie. associations). If I understand correctly, adding it into the groupby would mean I'm grabbing the latest combination of customer and associations combined, but I only want to grab latest off the `customer` column and not look at multiple columns together.

#### Edit:

I might be onto something by adding:

```
val val_columns = Seq("value.lastRefresh", "value.associations")
    .map(x => last(col(x)).alias(x))
```

Curious on thoughts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last value using spark window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468056/get-the-last-value-using-spark-window-function)

Comment: you should try to avoid [last](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#last), as the results are not non-deterministic. You are probably looking for [max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#max), and you can add additional columns with [max_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#max_by)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the latest customer data by the timestamp column, you can just order your dataframe by `value.timestamp` and apply `limit(1)`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.orderBy(desc("value.timestamp")).limit(1).show()
```

Comment: Implementation detail: finding the max should be simpler (O(N) complexity) than sorting + taking the head (typically O(NlogN), ymmv). Especially on a distributed computing platform, this is crucial, sorting surely will cause ALL data shuffling around the cluster, when a max operation will need only one row per partition to be moved around - a dramatic difference. Now, the execution planner / optimizer may know that orderBy + limit is a simpler problem than orderBy alone, but I'd still prefer writing a "maxBy" request, than a "sort + limit", just in case.